# Comparing geography column using STContains slow down the query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, spatial-query, spatial-index

I want to compare two geography column using StContains function but it slow down the query and output is obtained after 30-40 seconds which is a huge performance issue.

I am using below query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
            T.[LocationID], G.[Boundary].STContains(ESP.GeographyValue)
    FROM    [#TempTable] T
    CROSS JOIN [dbo].[GeographyTable] G
    INNER JOIN [dbo].LocationTable ESP ON T.LocationID = ESP.LocationID
    WHERE   G.[ID] = 1
```

Here both **Boundary** and **GeographyValue** are geography data type.

If i remove **G.[Boundary].STContains(ESP.GeographyValue)** then query is executed in 0 second so the main performance issue is due to StContains.

The result set contains **7000 records** which may not be the issue.

**Update:**

I have added spatial index to both the columns but still the execution is slow. By running a simple query it takes 10 secs.I used below query:

```
select ES.* from LocationTable ES INNER JOIN GeographyTable G ON ES.GeographyValue.STEquals(G.Boundary) = 1 Where G.Id = 1
```

I also tried STContains but still no luck.

Comment: What is the purpose of this query that you need to compare 7000 different locations?  Spatial comparisons are complex and resource intensive so can take a while and you are doing 7000 of them!  Do you have a spatial index on your Geography columns?

Comment: I have a list of Geography on UI through which user can select one of then and I want to compare GeographyTable with matching location. LocationTable is present in another database so I cannot add GeographyTable ID column to it. Spatial index is not present in both the table. Can you guide to which table I need to add it and how?

Comment: Spatial indexes go on your spatial columns...  If your users are selecting *one* Geography via your UI, why are you comparing all 7000?  Just compare the one they select.

Comment: I only have Id of GeographyTable and I want to get records from LocationTable based on it. I don't have relation of GeographyTable and LocationTable. The only common field is Boundary from GeographyTable and GeographyValue from LocationTable. So is there any way to compare both of this? If i use STContain and StEquals then it takes 30 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Force your code to use spatial index using below code
`[dbo].[GeographyTable] G WITH (INDEX(SI_Geofence_Boundary))`

Your revised query will look like,

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
            T.[LocationID], G.[Boundary].STContains(ESP.GeographyValue)
    FROM    [#TempTable] T
    CROSS JOIN [dbo].[GeographyTable] G WITH (INDEX(SI_Geofence_Boundary))
    INNER JOIN [dbo].LocationTable ESP ON T.LocationID = ESP.LocationID
    WHERE   G.[ID] = 1
```

It would reduce execution time from  30-40 seconds to 2-3 seconds.

For more information review the [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/isaac/2008/08/29/is-my-spatial-index-being-used/)